# Ti.App.fireEvent - Reference error Ti is not defined

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have this simple Titanium js script.

app.js

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
    var webview = Ti.UI.createWebView({
        url: 'logging.html'
    });
    webview.addEventListener('help',function(){
        alert('help');
    });
    win.add(webview);
    win.open();
```

logging.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a onclick="Ti.App.fireEvent('help')">Help</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

when I click on the Help link, the console gives me `Reference Error: Ti is not defined`.

I also tried changing Ti with Titanium, but same error.

------------- EDIT ----------

this error comes only with web browser. iOS works perfectly. but

### when titanium studio compiles the project for web mobile, I can see titanium.js and TI/* folder, so I guess it can't load Ti object. can anyone explain me why?

Comment: Are you sure you are including and successfully loading the Titanium.js script?

Comment: I'm not sure. how can I check that it loads/be included?

Comment: Use a debugger tool such a firebug for firefox or developer tools for chrome and look at your network traffic. Google it, there are lots of ways.

Comment: actually I already use Firebug, but that info is not present. what I can see is the Titanium compiler that says
`[INFO] :   Assembling titanium.js`

the only "console print" I see in firebug is the one I mentioned in the problem: `Reference error Ti is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution!

simply add to all of your html pages the simple script below

```
var Ti = window.parent.Ti
```

have fun!

**EDIT**:

**from sdk version 3.0.2GA on, I guess they fixed it. now it calls Ti sdk without that hack!****

Answer (score 0):

First, change:

```
webview.addEventListener('help',function(){
    alert('help');
});
```

To:

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('help',function(){
    alert('help');
});
```

And second: Call "Ti.App.fireEvent()" without the final "s" in your HTML file.

Comment: thanks Bruno, but it was a bad spelling, so I have the write code. I tried both, but same error...

Answer (score 0):

after some tests, I found that the previous code works perfectly on iOS phisical device/simulator and Android.

it doesn't on android web browser emulator and normal mobile browser (Firefox as mobile web app)

so, it seems that Titanium api calls will never work on web browsers because of "normal javascript library doesn't have `Titanium.*` or `Ti.*`".

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it worked

```
window.parent.TiApp.fireEvent
```